# How to interpret this formal language definition?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology

I am asked to construct a PDA to accept the language:

$\qquad \{w \in \{0, 1\}^* : \#_{0}(w) \ge \#_{1}(w)\}$

I am wondering how to interpret the $\#$ symbols and everything. Could someone please explain what exactly this means and how to construct it?

Comment: Your PDA must accept exactly those binary words where the number of zeros is at least the number of ones.

Comment: Oh so it means that the accepted string could be any random string of 0 and 1's as long as the number of 0's in the string is = or more than 1's

Comment: yes. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty standard notation for

$\qquad \#_a(w) = |w|_a = $ number of occurrences of $a$ in $w$.

Building a PDA for this language is straight-forward. Find a hint below.

> Use the stack to count $\#_0 - \#_1$ in the processed prefix of the input. Figure out how to model negative numbers.